# Adding some details to TikZ fig

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a TikZ generated picture, but couldn't add some details.

My example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
  {\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {\wire[thick,red]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
     \wire[thick,blue]{G-\i}{{(\i+1)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
    }
  \draw[<->] ($(G-0-3)!-0.5!(G-0-3)$) -- +(-0.5,0) node[above]{$\kappa_{1}$};
  \draw[<->] ($(B-1-4)!0.25!(B-1-5)$) -- +(-0.5,0) node[above]{$\kappa_{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Figure is [image]

I couldn't add a blue in the beginning and a red wire at the end. Also I want $\kappa_{1}$ and $\kappa_{2}$ in the middle of the two wires above <-->. How to go about?

Comment: Could you better explain what does `Also I want $\kappa_{1}$ and $\kappa_{2}$ in the middle of the two wires above <-->.` mean?

Comment: if you want blue first, then change the `\i+1` to `\i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One blue line to the left and a red one to the right is easy, just interchange the colors inside `\foreach` `draw` commands.

The second question about kappa labels is not clear for me, so this is just a guess.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
{\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {
        \wire[thick,blue]{G-\i}{{(\i)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
        \wire[thick,red]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
    }
    \draw[<->] ($(G-1-2)!-0.5!(G-2-3)$) -- +(-0.5,0) node[midway,above]{$\kappa_{1}$};
    \draw[<->] ($(B-0-3)!-0.5!(B-0-4)$) -- +(-0.5,0) node[midway, above]{$\kappa_{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: One last and only thing, what does `(G-1-2)!0.5!(G-1-3)`. What does this values mean?